# excel sheet wont scroll after adding userforms

Tags: vba, excel

I have buttons for going to other sheets in my workbook so I can hide other tabs to keep it cleaner. Everything worked fine until I added some userforms into the mix. Now when I use my button to `activate` another sheet it goes there but sometimes won't allow me to scroll. It happens when I change sheets after about 6 times, then it hangs. Seems like the userform isn't unloading properly.

**What I do to get excel to respond is to change sheets with the defualt tab at the bottom (some sheets show 2 tabs some show only 1).**

I have my userforms load as `vbmodeless`

Properties for each userform modal is `False`

*One of my userforms*

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I've been trying a bunch of things to get my worksheet to acts as normal with the userforms and nothing.

*Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.*

Comment: Aside from a code fix, I've found that by double clicking on any cell on the sheet you regain your ability to scroll.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Add `Application.screenupdating=true` in the `CancelButton_Click()` Also you do not need to hide and then unload it. you can directly unload it.

Comment: @dwirony double clicking doesn't work on mine. @siddharth Rout `screenupdating = true` didn't do anything.

Comment: Try my solution below. I tested it a couple times and it worked for me (on a document that I have the same issue).

Comment: Can I see your workbook? If yes then feel free to upload it in a free file sharing site and share the link here

Comment: to scroll on sheet you need the focus to be NOT on the userform.
Wich you can achive with that code : `AppActivate ThisWorkbook.Application.Caption`

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier added in your suggested code. that did not work. Thx tho

Answer (score 0):

Plug this in after `Unload Me` and see if that fixes it.

`ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1`

Comment: Also as Siddharth Rout pointed out, no need for both `Me.Hide` and `Unload Me`. Just use `Unload Me`

Comment: Yeah, i was trying a bunch of different things to get this to work. also `ScrollRow = 1` didn't change anything. It looks like its something to do with the userform that has a photo that I pasted into userform properties.

Comment: Very strange... I've had issues before with my userform putting `Focus` on an object instead of my textbox, etc. Maybe you gotta fiddle around with that...

Comment: I deleted all my userforms to check and see if the problem continues and it does. So now im not sure where its coming from.

Comment: yes i am. And they need to be frozen, can i unfreeze then run the command then re freeze?

Comment: That's what I'd try. `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False` Then right after `Rows("2:2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True` (if you're freezing the top row`

Comment: Ok, added in UnFreeze and Freeze code to each sheet. Code works as expected but problem continues. When each sheet had its own button everything worked fine, but it seems that the problem started when i changed to a custom_popup_menu (More Links = Less Buttons). Maybe that code is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

So it helped me with 2013 Excel Verison. 
Just when you assign a macro to a button to open a Userform just type this

Userform.Show False

What it does when you transition to another sheet you can still do stuff with user form open, so you just close it and everything must work fine

Comment: Of course instead of Userform you type in the name of the form that you've created